# Unit testing Java switch - case logic - multiple separate functions or multiple calls

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Below is a sample switch statements in one of classes that I have to write unit tests for. I have removed logic under each case from below code.

```
switch (insurance.getInsuranceType()) {
                case None:{
                    break;}

                case Health: {

                    break;}

                case Auto:{
                    break;}

                case WorkersCompensation:{
                    break;}

                default:{}

            }
```

I have to cover each switch paths but to reach to this switch point in function to be tested, I have to put 10s of whens and corresponding verify statements ( I am using Mockito for mocking ). To cover each path, I have an option to write as many functions as there are cases in switch statements ( for various `InsuranceType` data ) or I write single function and keep repeating same code by changing `InsuranceType`data. Test code is duplicated in both ways and second way is more error prone for verifying calls on mocked objects. My question is about any other way ( that helps to avoid duplicate code and clean test code ) and how do experienced developers handle switch statements in their unit tests( As there are situations in my code where there are 10s of cases )? Code was written by some other developers and I have been asked to write unit tests to increase test coverage and put additional unit tests. I need to know if there are generic practices about multiple logic branches ( not necessarily only for switch statements but sometimes there are multiple if - else if - else logic and 3 -4 level deep nested conditions too ). insurance.getInsuranceType() is an enum. 
Please suggest.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer:** This is an opinion, but I'm phrasing it as an answer because a comment is not long enough to fully explain myself.

In general, `switch` statements indicate poor code design.  In the above case, for example:

```
public Coverage returnCoverage() {  // I'm just making up a method name here
    switch (insurance.getInsuranceType()) {
        case None: {
            ...
            break;
        }
        case Health: {
            ...
            break;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

...it looks like you have some method whose logic branches on the insurance type.  This indicates to me that your insurance type should actually have the logic.  For example:

```
public interface InsuranceType {    // not enum
    Coverage getCoverage();
}

public class NoInsurance implements InsuranceType {
    public Coverage getCoverage() {
        ...
    }
}

public class HealthInsurance implements InsuranceType {
    public Coverage getCoverage() {
        ...
    }
}

// etc.
```

Then, your `Insurance` object would contain an instance of `InsuranceType` just as it currently does.  You can do the same thing with `enum`s -- implement a method differently per enumerated value -- but it's a bit messy.

If you do this with all your `switch` statements, you should see a coherent `InsuranceType` domain object start to emerge, and you should begin to see other code that can be moved into that class hierarchy.  Furthermore, if you need to add a new type of insurance in the future, you don't have to go searching through all your code trying to find all the places where you switch on `InsuranceType` -- instead, you just create a new implementing class and everything magically works.

To answer your question about testing, if you do the above, then your `switch` statement goes away.  Therefore, you can test each of your `InsuranceType`s in isolation without a whole lot of mocking necessary.

The same goes for highly nested if statements.  Break them out into separate methods, and move the logic where it belongs, and consolidate it.  You will typically find a lot of cut 'n' pasted code where the branches are very similar.  If you use an IDE, look for an Extract Method refactoring, and make sure that you select the "detect duplicates" option.  Hopefully you can reduce the amount of code you have to maintain, and the complexity of that code, and leave it in a better state for the next developer to maintain it!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well done! Although _an opinion_ this is actually a very good suggestion.

Comment: @Eric - Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I can make recommendations to change code but that depends on being approved.

Comment: @Sabir_Khan Alas.  Can you hand your approvers a copy of Martin Fowler's *Refactoring*, or Robert Martin's *Clean Code*, or Eric Evans' *Domain-Driven Design*? :)

Comment: @EricGalluzzo - First , let me read myself :) I mean , approvers are very open to suggestions but there is a process.

Comment: Another thought here would be to write the tests before the code as it will reduce the likelihood of writing the switch statement to begin with.

Comment: @unigeek Definitely agree.  Unfortunately in this case, it sounds like Sabir_Khan is stuck with a legacy code base that he is tasked with writing tests for.  But certainly TDD is a much better approach to writing code in general.

Comment: yes, thats correct. Its legacy code with very few unit tests and I am asked to write unit tests wherever missing. For new code development, TDD is being followed.